# Getting "io.restassured.internal.RestAssuredResponseImpl@268cbb86" while printing the Response in API AUTOMATION

Tags: api, automation, rest-assured

When sending the body i can able to find the booking confirmation ,but when i try to print the response getting like "io.restassured.internal.RestAssuredResponseImpl@268cbb86 "

public static void main(String[] args)  {

```
    details();
    bodyhashmap();
    
    senddata();
    System.out.println(body);
    
    
    Response resp1=given().header("Content-Type","application/json")
            .log()
            .all()
            .body(body)
            .post("https://restful-booker.herokuapp.com/booking");  
            resp1.prettyPrint();
            String as=resp1.jsonPath().get("firstname");
            System.out.println(resp1.getBody().toString());         
            
}
```

}

Answer (score 2):

Method `toString()` is not valid in this case, try to use `resp1.getBody().asString()` instead.